# SVG and mouseover

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm a JS newbie and have converted an SVG to JS using Raphael. I'm trying to make an interactive map of the USA with mouseover effects over multiple paths and circles.

I have the states as variables with a parent variable and the cities I've visted as variables with a parent variable. Here's a snippet of my JS:

```
var states = rsr.set();

var connecticut = rsr.path("M877.198,184.1l-0.6-4.2l-0.8-4.4l-1.602-6L870,170.4l-21.802,4.8l0.602,3.3l1.5,7.3v8.102   l-1.102,2.3l1.802,2.101l5-3.399l3.6-3.2l1.9-2.1l0.8,0.6l2.7-1.5l5.198-1.1L877.198,184.1z").attr({fill: '#D3D3D3','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'});
connecticut.node.id = 'Connecticut';
states.push(connecticut);


var cities = rsr.set();

var losAngeles = rsr.circle(87, 349, 5).attr({fill: '#3F3F3F','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'});
cities.push(losAngeles);
```

I'm having trouble creating mouseover effects on both the states AND cities. I'm thinking it could have something to do with the z-index?

I've written these for loops so far but only one ever works at a time.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= states.length; i++) {
    states[i].mouseover(function() {
        this.animate({
            fill: '#fff',
            transform: 's1.05'
            }, 200);
    });
    states[i].mouseout(function() {
        this.animate({
            fill: '#D3D3D3',
            transform: 's1'
            }, 200);
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i <= cities.length; i++) {
    cities[i].mouseover(function() {
        this.animate({
            r : 10,
        }, 200);
    });
    cities[i].mouseout(function() {
        this.animate({
            r : 5,
        }, 200);
    });
}
```

I've tried using toFront(); and toBack(); and still can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think as I assume you have overlayed elements, you need to clarify how you actually want them to work if hovering over 2 elements at the same time.

Comment: The mouseout event works on the states when the mouse enters a city. I just can't get the mouseover event to trigger on a city. So how can I tackle the overlay?

Comment: there is no z-index support within SVG elements

Comment: Turns out it was a problem with my for loops, I need to put i < states.length and i < cities.length instead of <= for both. Such a simple fix